# How can I ask cloudflare to return json instead of html

Tags: rest, cloudflare

My code consumes an API from XYZ which is being served through CloudFlare. From time to time, the XYZ server is overloaded and the CloudFlare -> XYZ connection times out. When that happens, I get a human readable HTML page from CloudFlare.

Is there anything I can include in my HTTP request to tell CloudFlare that I am an App, not a person, and to report any errors in a JSON response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have any control over the Cloudflare settings for the API? Cloudflare's recommendations on [using Cloudflare with your API](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200504045-Using-Cloudflare-with-your-API) suggest disabling Always Online and SmartErrors for API URLs to prevent this.

Without changing those settings there's nothing you can do in a request to change the response you get in this situation.

Comment: No I have no control over the third party providing the API. I was kinda hoping I could influence it solely from the client. I would have thought that an http Accept: application/json header would do the trick, but apparantly not.

Comment: @pinoyyid Sorry but, even if Clodflare honors your `Accept` header this is a crazy quesiton. What if XYZ decides to not use Clodflare anymore? It's a really bad decision to rely on a 3rd party's 3rd party. It should not be hard to check whether the response is json or not in your own code.

Answer (score 1):

This might achieve what you're looking for: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/206777107-What-is-Enable-Origin-Error-Pages-

With that enabled you can send your own error pages -- which presumably you'll send in JSON instead of HTML.

Comment: unfortunately I have no control over the service or its CloudFlare configuration

Comment: ah  my mistake -- there's not much you can do unfortunately in that case. Could be worth pointing out this issue to whoever runs the API -- they may not be aware.